# In rails do a query join that in a new query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

What I want is something akin to this

```
models = Model0.where( attr: true )
results1 = Model1.joins(models)
results2 = Model2.joins(models)
```

I know I could do it in reverse if I wanted to

```
joined1 = Model1.joins(:model0s)
results1 = joined1.where('model0s.attr' => true )
joined2 = Model2.joins(:model0s)
results2 = joined2.where('model0s.attr' => true )
```

but this means redundant where clauses which I actually have many of.

So is something like the first example possible?

Edit:

I want to do this dynamically. Which is also why I don't want to duplicate the information
Currently my code is closer to.

```
def filter_model0_by_criteria(model_to_filter, criteria)
    to_filter = model_to_filter.joins(:model0s)
    unless( criteria[:model0_attr1].blank? )
        to_filter = to_filter.where( model0_attr1: criteria[:model0_attr1] )
    end
    unless( criteria[:model0_attr2].blank? )
        to_filter = to_filter.where( model0_attr2: criteria[:model0_attr2] )
    end
    #more conditionals, not all are equals some are > and < etc.
    to_filter
end

def filter_model1_by_criteria(criteria)
    to_filter = self.filter_model0_by_criteria(Model1, criteria)
    unless( criteria[:model1_attr1].blank? )
        to_filter = to_filter.where( model1_attr1: criteria[:model1_attr1] )
    end
    unless( criteria[:model1_attr2].blank? )
        to_filter = to_filter.where( model1_attr2: criteria[:model1_attr2] )
    end
    #more conditionals, not all are equals some are > and < etc.
    to_filter
end

def filter_model2_by_criteria(criteria)
    to_filter = self.filter_model0_by_criteria(Model2, criteria)
    unless( criteria[:model2_attr1].blank? )
        to_filter = to_filter.where( model2_attr1: criteria[:model2_attr1] )
    end
    unless( criteria[:model2_attr2].blank? )
        to_filter = to_filter.where( model2_attr2: criteria[:model2_attr2] )
    end
    #more conditionals, not all are equals some are > and < etc.
    to_filter
   end

results1 = self.filter_model1_by_criteria( criteria )
results2 = self.filter_model2_by_criteria( criteria )
```

The so there is kind of two redundancies here the logic and there where clauses.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is

```
class Model1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attr_model0s, -> { where attr: true }, :class_name => "Model0"
end

class Model2 < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attr_model0s, -> { where attr: true }, :class_name => "Model0"
end

Model1.joins(:attr_model0s)
Model2.joins(:attr_model0s)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply I forgot to mention that the where was based on logic that is user input. I will edit my question

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the closest thing to what I wanted was merge
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-merge

So using my initial example

```
models = Model0.where( attr: true )
results1 = Model1.joins(:model0s).merge(models)
results2 = Model2.joins(:model0s).merge(models)
```